# How can i disable popups in headless chrome?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to disable no user-interaction window opening in headless chrome(86).
In regular chrome, The browser asks the user if he/she wants to open a window, but in headless chrome, it opens without asking anything.
I've found some tricks for this but none of them worked so far. I've tried this:

```
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["disable-popup-blocking"])
```

and this:

```
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking");
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem the following code:

```
options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default')
```